# Finding Roots of tenth degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I know that there are no explicit formulas to find roots for polynomials of degree higher than $4$.

I have to find all the roots of the polynomial $ f(z) = 1+z^2+z^4+z^6+z^8+z^{10}$

I found two roots, $\pm i$.

Can you suggest of a method/(s) to find all the roots.

Comment: Consider $f(z)\times(z^2-1)$.

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation.

Comment: Is that clearer?

Comment: Do you have a specific area where you need to find these roots? As you have found two roots, you can divide $f(z)$ by $(z^2+1)$ and then continue finding extra roots. You may also check for the roots' multiplicity via Horner's scheme.

Comment: Replace $z^2$ by $x$, equation reduces to $5$ degree polynomial. Already you have one root $x=-1$, so you are left with finding roots of a $4$ degree polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to show some other method:
For $t=z^2$ your equation becomes:
$$
1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5=0
$$
that can be factorized as:
$$
(1+t)(1+t^2+t^4)=(1+t)(1+t^4+2t^2-t^2)=(1+t)(1+t^2+t)(1+t^2-t)
$$
and solved.

Or noting that:
$$
(1-t^6)=(1-t)(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5)
$$
we can say that the roots of $1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5=0$ are the roots of $1-t^6=0$ (six sixth roots of unit easy to find) different from $t=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have $+i,-i$, take the product of the root coefficients $(x-i)(x+i) = (x^2+1)$ and divide the polynomial with it.